# How can I enable Airflow to send email alerts only after multiple task instance failures?

Tags: python, airflow, alert

We have some DAG's that run often, and are occasionally flaky even with retries. We'd like to only get alerts if this DAG (or tasks within the DAG) fail multiple times in a row.

i.e., if the DAG runs every hour, we'd like to get an email alert from Airflow only if it fails each hour 3 times in a row.

Is there a way we can configure Airflow to do this?

Answer (score 0):

@Zak

There are a couple of approaches to this.

The first option is to programmatically create a function that monitors the try_number. Then you can use an on_failure_callback or perhaps even a BranchPythonOperator to send an email based on your desired threshold

Within [from airflow import DagRun](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/dagrun/index.html), we can solve your question:

1. Using .find to get an instance of a specific DAG
2. Sort it for the last run
3. Zoom into a specific task within that instance
4. Within get_try_instance, you can call .[try_number](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/taskinstance/index.html) which is set to 1 by default
5. You can pair this with an `on_failure_callback` inside your default parameters `on_failure_callback: name_of_function_to_send_email_with_retries`
6. You can import `from airflow.utils.email import send_email` to send this email

Something like the below should suffice, I have not executed this myself.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.models import DagRun
from airflow.utils.email import send_email
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

def check_task_failure_count(dag_id, task_id):
    """ Returns the number of times a task has failed in the last dag run

    Args:
        dag_id (str): The dag_id to check
        task_id (str): The task_id to check
    Returns:
        List - The number of times a task has failed in the last dag run
    """
    last_dag_run = DagRun.find(dag_id=dag_id)
    last_dag_run.sort(key=lambda x: x.execution_date, reverse=True)
    return last_dag_run[0].get_task_instance(task_id).try_number

def failture_email(dag_id, task_id, **context):
    """ Emails when a task id fails 3 times

    Args:
        dag_id (str): The dag_id to check
        task_id (str): The task_id to check
        context (dict): The dag_run context
    """
    # retained this for posterity, however it is not used in this example
    # instead we use the retries value from the DAG context via 'retries' : 3
    last_dag_run = DagRun.find(dag_id=dag_id)
    last_dag_run.sort(key=lambda x: x.execution_date, reverse=True)
    retries = last_dag_run[0].get_task_instance(task_id).try_number

    msg = "DAG/TASK Failed!"
    subject = f"DAG {dag_run} has failed"
    send_email(to=your_emails, subject=subject, html_content=msg)

default_args = {
  'on_failure_callback': failture_email,
  'retries': 3
}

with DAG(
  'stack_overflow_ans_2',
  tags = ['SO'],
  start_date = datetime(2022, 1, 1),
  schedule_interval = None,
  catchup = False,
  is_paused_upon_creation = False,
  default_args=default_args
) as dag:

  t1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id = 'task_that_will_fail',
    python_callable = some_function_that_will_fail,
  )

  t1
```

The second option is to harness the BaseOperator, and inside your default parameters pass in the retry key/value pairs. Naturally, there is a tradeoff between absolute control of the process which can occur through route 1 or the ease of route 2.

```
default_args = {
    'start_date': datetime(2022, 1, 1),
    'email': ['YOUR_EMAIL'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': True,
    'retry_exponential_backoff': True,
    'retry_delay' = timedelta(seconds=300)
    'retries': 3
}
```

Both routes assume you have correctly configured [Apache Airflow to send emails](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/email-config.html).